# HTML5 Canvas browser-like fonts (sub-pixel anti-aliasing)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts, antialiasing

When browsers render fonts, they seem to give it a slightly colored anti-alias (sub-pixel). In contrast, when using HTML5 Canvas to `fillText`, you are given a single color anti-alias. I find the colored version to be much more appealing to the eyes.

So my question is, how can I use HTML5 Canvas to draw more browser-like fonts?

[image: Comparison]